# Erro com o certificado na emissão de NFC-e

Tags: php, soap, nfe

Estou tentando emitir um cupom fiscal em PHP ultilizando o sped-nfe. Os arquivos xml estão sendo gerados. Xmls assinados também estão, na hora de envio a receita, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
{"error":"Envio: An error occurred while trying to communication via soap, unable to load client cert: -8018 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR) [https:\/\/nfce-homologacao.svrs.rs.gov.br\/ws\/NfeAutorizacao\/NFeAutorizacao4.asmx]"}
```

Já verifiquei o caminho e a senha do certificado A1, ambos estão corretos, e quando não estão, o erro é diferente. Também verifiquei a validade do certificado, e está tudo certo com ele.

```
try {
        $xml_assinado = file_get_contents($pasta."assinadas/".$chave.".xml");
        $idLote = substr(str_replace(',', '', number_format(microtime(true)*1000000, 0)), 0, 15);
        $response_envio = $tools->sefazEnviaLote([$xml_assinado], $idLote); // O erro é na chamada dessa função
        var_dump($xml_assinado);
        $stdCl = new Standardize($response_envio);
        var_dump($xml_assinado);
        $arr_envio = $stdCl->toArray();
  if ($arr_envio['cStat'] == 103) { // OK ENVIO
            $recibo_envio = $arr_envio['infRec']['nRec'];
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "Envio: ".$arr_envio['xMotivo']." (".$arr_envio['cStat'].")"));
        die;
    }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
   echo json_encode(array("error" => "Envio: ".$e->getMessage()));
    die;
}
```

Função de envio:

```
public function sefazEnviaLote(
    $aXml,
    $idLote = '',
    $indSinc = 0,
    $compactar = false,
    &$xmls = []
) {
    if (!is_array($aXml)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Envia Lote: XMLs de NF-e deve ser um array!');
    }
    if ($indSinc == 1 && count($aXml) > 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Envio sincrono deve ser usado para enviar '
            . 'uma UNICA nota por vez. Você está tentando enviar varias.');
    }
    $servico = 'NfeAutorizacao';
    $this->checkContingencyForWebServices($servico);
    if ($this->contingency->type != '') {
        // Em modo de contingencia esses XMLs deverão ser modificados e re-assinados e retornados
        // no parametro $xmls para serem armazenados pelo aplicativo pois serão alterados.
        foreach ($aXml as $doc) {
            //corrigir o xml para o tipo de contigência setado
            $xmls[] = $this->correctNFeForContingencyMode($doc);
        }
        $aXml = $xmls;
    }
    $ax = [];
    foreach ($aXml as $xml) {
        $ax[] = trim(preg_replace("/<\?xml.*?\?>/", "", $xml));
    }
    $sxml = trim(implode("", $ax));
    $this->servico($servico, $this->config->siglaUF, $this->tpAmb);
    $request = "<enviNFe xmlns=\"$this->urlPortal\" versao=\"$this->urlVersion\">"
        . "<idLote>$idLote</idLote>"
        . "<indSinc>$indSinc</indSinc>"
        . "$sxml"
        . "</enviNFe>";
    $this->isValid($this->urlVersion, $request, 'enviNFe');
    $this->lastRequest = $request;
    //montagem dos dados da mensagem SOAP
    $parameters = ['nfeDadosMsg' => $request];
    $body = "<nfeDadosMsg xmlns=\"$this->urlNamespace\">$request</nfeDadosMsg>";
    if ($compactar) {
        $gzdata = base64_encode(gzencode($request, 9, FORCE_GZIP));
        $parameters = ['nfeDadosMsgZip' => $gzdata];
        $body = "<nfeDadosMsgZip xmlns=\"$this->urlNamespace\">$gzdata</nfeDadosMsgZip>";
    }
    $this->lastResponse = $this->sendRequest($body, $parameters);
    return $this->lastResponse;
}

/**
 * Check status of Batch of NFe sent by receipt of this shipment
 * @param string $recibo
 * @param int $tpAmb
 * @return string
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function sefazConsultaRecibo($recibo, $tpAmb = null)
{
    if (empty($recibo)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Consulta Recibo: numero do recibo vazio!');
    }
    if (empty($tpAmb)) {
        $tpAmb = $this->tpAmb;
    }
    //carrega serviço
    $servico = 'NfeRetAutorizacao';
    $this->checkContingencyForWebServices($servico);
    $this->servico($servico, $this->config->siglaUF, $tpAmb);
    if ($this->urlService == '') {
        $msg = "A consulta de NFe nao esta disponivel na SEFAZ {$this->config->siglaUF}!";
        throw new RuntimeException($msg);
    }
    $request = "<consReciNFe xmlns=\"$this->urlPortal\" versao=\"$this->urlVersion\">"
        . "<tpAmb>$tpAmb</tpAmb>"
        . "<nRec>$recibo</nRec>"
        . "</consReciNFe>";
    $this->isValid($this->urlVersion, $request, 'consReciNFe');
    $this->lastRequest = $request;
    $parameters = ['nfeDadosMsg' => $request];
    $body = "<nfeDadosMsg xmlns=\"$this->urlNamespace\">$request</nfeDadosMsg>";
    $this->lastResponse = $this->sendRequest($body, $parameters);
    return $this->lastResponse;
}
```

Perdão pela extensão dos códigos

Ambiente: Fedora 26

Comment: dá uma olhada se o caminho onde são salvos os arquivos temporários você tem permissão de escrita

Comment: Estão com todas as persmissões, os arquivos conseguem ser salvos, só não consigo me comunicar e receber o xml do sefaz (aprovado ou não)

Comment: então pode ser um problema na encriptação, só desativar: exemplo:
$soap->setEncriptPrivateKey(false);

Comment: Desliguei, continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: então mostra o seu código por favor para analisarmos

Comment: Atualizei com os códigos